# Batch file outputting too many lines

Tags: batch-file

I want to log my CPU Usage in a file, using a batch, this is my code so far:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do echo CPU: %%p >> test.txt
```

The problem now is, that instead of the expected output "CPU: (cpu usage)"
It outputs:

> CPU: (cpu usage)
>   CPU:

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMIC by default outputs in a format which includes characters not compatible with the method you've chosen. Please try the following single line batch file instead:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=L" %%A In ('WMIC CPU Get LoadPercentage') Do @For %%B In (%%A) Do @(Echo=CPU: %%B)>"test.txt"
```

Comment: Works, great! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: oh but you did one mistake, you did cpu temp in the output line, instead of usage, but i fixed it :D

Comment: @DJNoRealityTXC_TryhardOne please explain my mistake, I didn't output `Temp`, just `CPU: <Value of LoadPercentage>` according to your exact same command. If you wanted the temperature, you shouldn't have used `Get LoadPercentage`. Your question was about the unwanted extra line, that's what my answer demonstrated.

Comment: ah wait, then that was in my script already somehow, my mistake then, sorry :D